# NGINX: add_before_body throwing a 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am having issues trying to set up a proxy pass and write some code to the top of my page.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ns1.example.co.uk;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost/;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }

         location ~ \.php$ {
             root           html;
             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index  index.php;
             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include        fastcgi_params;
             add_before_body    myscripts/tobemirrored.php;
         }
}
```

It is successfully adding to the page but it is getting a 404 error, any ideas?

Comment: The ngx_http_addition_module module is not built by default. Did you enable it, when building nginx --with-http_addition_module configuration parameter?

Comment: Yes, the module is enabled.

Comment: For me URI `myscripts/tobemirrored.php` looks recursive to `location ~ \.php$`, hence you create an endless loop on any PHP page (a `.php`-URL needs `myscripts/tobemirrored.php` which is a `.php`-URL which needs `myscripts/tobemirrored.php` which needs `myscripts/tobemirrored.php` which needs .. and so on).  Also `add_before_body` adds to the **response**, not to the request, so FastCGI will not receive `myscripts/tobemirrored.php`, instead output of `myscripts/tobemirrored.php` is put in front of the data sent to the browser.